# analytics:reportChart Filter Column name Account.ParentId is wrong [For the filter 1: Specify a valid filterable column because ParentId]

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, dashboard, custom-reports

Here I'm trying to display Report charts in visualforce page, but I'm getting an error:

> [For the filter 1: Specify a valid filterable column because ParentId is invalid]

Actually, for Column names (API names), I looked in view page source, Workbench so many places online, but I couldn't find the right one.

I need you guys help to find out Column names for `analytics:reportchart` for the field Account.ParentId.

Look into below image and code for reference:

[image]

---

## Code

```
<analytics:reportChart filter="[{column:'ParentId',operator:'equals',value:'001O00001IEpmW'}]" size="tiny" ReportId="00O9000009iEe" /> `
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run below code in Anonymous Window.In JSON Output, you need to identify under detailColumns what is the exact label for your column. Based on that , you will apply the filter. For instance, if it says ParentId, you will mention parentId in column parameter.

Report reportRec = [SELECT Id FROM Report WHERE Id = '00ON0000000k7CyMAI'];

```
Reports.ReportResults reportResult = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportRec.Id, true);

system.debug('Test'+JSON.serialize(reportResult));
```